# Query to Filter Datatable by date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable with these columns:

> |  Id  |  CustomerId  |  PaymentAmount  |  NextScheduleDate  |

All columns contain string values (for example, row 0 cell of *NextScheduleDate* might be the string "11/1/2020").
I would like to filter it and create a new DataTable made up of only of the rows where the *NextScheduleDate* values fall inside a date range.  So the user selects the range, and the method should filter the table accordingly.
Some of the *NextScheduleDate* cells values may be null.
I'm pretty new to Linq, so any and all help is much appreciated. Here's my method so far, which does not work at all.

```
protected void LoadPayments()
{
    // User provides textbox values
    string startDate = txtStartDateRange.Text;
    string endDate = txtEndDateRange.Text;

    // This methods gets ALL payments, some of which have already happened
    // and some of which are scheduled as future payments
    DataTable tblPayments = Payments.GetAllRecurringPayments();

    // We only want payments where the NextScheduleDate column value is the range selected by the user

    // How to filter so that NextScheduleDate is in between startDate and endDate?
    // (Needs to return values where startDate > NextScheduleDate > endDate

    DataTable futurePayments = tblPayments.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("NextScheduleDate") == ?????)
    .CopyToDataTable();

    // Bind
    grdPayments.DataSource = futurePayments;
    grdPayments.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("NextScheduleDate") == DateTime.Now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am showing the following code as is, I have not run it. I indicate where the code could break and under which circumstances.

For clarity, I assume that the dates you supply can be converted to DateTime using the Parse method.   If they can't, the reasoning remains valid, only you will use TryParse and provide logic for the cases the dates are not be valid.

Also, I'll assume that your database returns DBNull.Value when the content of the date field is empty.

```
protected void LoadPayments()
{
    // User provides textbox values
    string startDate = txtStartDateRange.Text;
    string endDate = txtEndDateRange.Text;
    // Converts dates to DateTime (breaks if Dates are not valid)
    DateTime s = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
    DateTime e = DateTime.Parse(endDate);

    // This methods gets ALL payments, some of which have already happened
    // and some of which are scheduled as future payments
    DataTable tblPayments = Payments.GetAllRecurringPayments();

    // We only want payments where the NextScheduleDate column value is the range selected by the user

    // How to filter so that NextScheduleDate is in between startDate and endDate?
    // (Needs to return values where startDate > NextScheduleDate > endDate

    DataTable futurePayments = tblPayments.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r =>
    {
        // Excludes if there is no date.
        // Assumes the DB returns DBNull.Value if the Field is null
        if (r.Field("NextScheduleDate") == DBNull.Value) { return false; }
        // Breaks if Date is not valid
        DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("NextScheduleDate"));
        if (d < s) { return false; }
        if (d > e) { return false; }
        return true;
    });

    .CopyToDataTable();

    // Bind
    grdPayments.DataSource = futurePayments;
    grdPayments.DataBind();
}
```